# A save function in F# that does not want to run

Tags: serialization, f#

I have borrowed the following save function to save values of any type to a given file (cheers to John Harrop, writer of F# for scientists).

```
    open System.IO
    open System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

    let save filename x =
       use stream =
         new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create)
       (new BinaryFormatter()).Serialize(stream, x);;
```

But F# is telling me that there is no body for the "use" part of the function. I seems to not like the final line but the intellisense is not giving me an error message when I hover.

Do I need to declare another namespace?

Can anyone advise? Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works on my machine! :-) If you're typing this directly into FSI try putting it in a script file and using 'Send to Interactive'. If you're *not*, remove `;;` on the last line.

Comment: How strange. It is the ( that it doesn't like, it expects and incomplete structured construct yadda, yadda.

Comment: I am putting this into a .fsx file and then sending to interactive, exactly as you say! Bizarro!

Comment: Which `(` does it not like? It worked as-is for me using 'Send to Interactive'.

Comment: Hmm, I just altered the indentation, I indented the "use" less, and now it seems fine. Curse you meaningful white space!!

Comment: `;;` can be used in file and not just FSI.